# Auto-Accept Facetime Calls in Mojave

Tags: facetime, plist, call

As in this previous question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49120467/facetime-autoacceptinvites

I want to use my mac to look at the state of my home from time to time (particularly to see whether my HomeKit Automation works). That would most easily be done by having the mac auto-accept FaceTime calls from my iPhone.

Previously, there have been the com.apple.FaceTime plist keys AutoAcceptInvites and AutoAcceptInvitesFrom, which could be used to configure the desired behavior. However, they do not seem to have the desired effect any more in Mojave.

Running `strings /Applications/FaceTime.app/Contents/MacOS/FaceTime | grep Auto` as the poster of the original solution for the old OSses yielded several results. The keys `AutoAcceptInvites` and `AutoAcceptInvitesFrom` are still there. Another promising one was `Auto-accepting invite: %@`. Since `%@` is the string format for an object in Cocoa (that is, a string for example), I guess this is something like a log message for an automatically accepted call. So it might still be possible.

Comment: Well, as we can see, apple has us covered for that option with the great group-facetime feature :D

Comment: Any solution on this one?